# error in calling soap function in php

Tags: php, soap

how can i get soap data in php from this site 
http://www2.rlcarriers.com/freight/shipping-resources/rate-quote-instructions

they have "GetRateQuote(string APIKey, RequestObjects.RateQuoteRequest request)"
 this function how can i call this from php soap

$client = new SoapClient('http://api.rlcarriers.com/1.0.1/RateQuoteService.asmx?WSDL');
//print_r($client);
//$result = $client->GetRateQuote('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.......',);

print_r($result);
?>
what should i have to pass in second parameter

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://api.rlcarriers.com/1.0.1/ShipmentTracingService.asmx?WSDL", array("trace" => 1));

$request = array(
    "APIKey" => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "request" => array(
        "TraceNumbers" => array(
            0 => "xxxxxxxxx"
        ),
        "TraceType" => "PRO",
        "FormatResults" => "true",
        "IncludeBlind" => "true",
        "OutputFormat" => "Standard"
    )
);

try {
    $response = $client->TraceShipment($request);
    print_r($response);
}
catch (SoapFault $exception) {
    print_r($exception);
}
```